# How to reuse oauth2 token from user (authorization_code) in a Rest Template

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-rest, spring-security-oauth2

I have 3 applications

1. Frontend application
2. OAuth2 authentication server
3. REST api (RepositoryRestResources)

My users have to log in before being able to use the frontend application. This happens through SSO. They receive a token which is validated by the client before being let in.

I would like to reuse this token to make api requests. My REST api application is secured with the same SSO login (it is a resource for the frontend client) but I have no clue how to "add the authorization header" to be used in the RestTemplate I use for api requests.

I create my restTemplate like this:

```
public static RestTemplate build()
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/hal+json"));
        converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(converter));
    }
```

my resource server configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Value("${resource.id}")
    private String resourceId;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception
    {
        resources.resourceId(resourceId);
    }


    @Bean
    public static TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer()
    {
        return new JwtTokenEnhancer();
    }


    @Bean
    public static JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter()
    {
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "somesecret".toCharArray());
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();

        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("pair"));
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public static TokenStore tokenStore()
    {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it using an intercepter an manually adding the Token from the security context.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new OAuthInterceptor());
```

In which the intercepter is defined as:

```
public class OAuthInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor
{

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationHolder holder;

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException
    {
        if (holder.getToken() == null)
        {
            //throw new IOException("Token not set");
            System.out.println("##################### Token not set! ###################");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("##################### Token found: " + holder.getToken());
            HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + holder.getToken());
        }

        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

I use an interface which I implement in my client app:

```
public interface AuthenticationHolder
{
    String getToken();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationHolder getAuthenticationHolder()
{
    return () ->
    {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(authentication != null && authentication.getDetails() instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationDetails)
        {
            return ((OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails()).getTokenValue();
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

Comment: AuthenticationHolder  is always null.. even after with Component annotation. Is this tested code or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that AuthenticationHolder  was some custom thing, so you probably just want to use SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); in stead.

Comment: OAuth2AuthenticationDetails auth = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
  ____ and from that____  
auth.getTokenValue()

Comment: To avoid NPE's I would suggest:
Optional<String> token = Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()).map(Authentication::getDetails).filter(details -> auth instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationDetails).map(OAuth2AuthenticationDetails.class::cast).map(OAuth2AuthenticationDetails::getToken) (untested)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@PreAuthorize(ROLE)` on the top of your methods, so when this method is called he will as for the Token then he will check if the provided Token has the necessary ROLE to use the method.

Of course that you will need to configure your API to connect to your OAuth Database.

Example:

`@PreAuthorize("ROLE_ADMIN")
public void deleteAll(){
  ...
}`

Comment: My api is set up correctly. The problem is the client's rest template does not "use" the authentication or better does not send the authorization header with its requests.